# Alternative to window.load and document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, undefined

**My Issue** I have an issue with a webpage where 1 in 100 page loads gives me an "Undefined is not defined" error. This error is caused by a jquery plugin being initialized before it is actually loaded. My current fix is to use window.load which works great but can take anywhere from 1 second to infinity depending on however long shareaholic decides to load (and it's faster than addthis).

**My Question** is there some way to initialize a plugin only after it has been loaded, like a Success event or something for including a plugin? I haven't been able to find anything.

Hopefully this will be useful to someone else who has run across this as well.

Comment: Try [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: You need to provide more detail on what this means: `This error is caused by a jquery plugin being initialized before it is actually loaded.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: pluginUrl,
    dataType: "script",
    success: initializePlugin
});
```

or just `$.getScript()`

Comment: I ended up using $.getScript() and this worked the best which is the reason I chose this as the correct answer. Adam's answer worked well too, but I chose to go with the $.getScript() so I give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to wait for a certain event that is not tied to the DOM, but is tied to the way your code executes. I find jQuery's ability to fire custom events excellent for this purpose.

e.g:

```
//start of script - do some asynchronous work
$.ajax({})
  .done(function() {
    //ready to initialize the plugin - trigger an event
    $(document).trigger('initializeMyPlugin');
  });


//listen for the event and initialize your plugin when it is fired
$(document)
 .on('initializeMyPlugin',function() {
   // initialization code
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works well, but I did decide to go with $.getScript()